# Solution to a linear Backward SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

In my [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4448856/constructing-the-solution-to-a-linear-backward-sde), Jose and I discussed about the solution to a linear backward SDE. I followed his steps and made it clear.

Besides, I read a paper from Professor Peng talk about the linear Backward SDE. In that paper, Professor Peng gave the result of the linear backward SDE:

> for $g(t,Y_t,Z_t) = a_tY_t + b_tZ_t + c_t$ is a linear function, the solution of $Y_t$ can be write as the following form:
>
> $$Y_t = E[X_T\xi + \int _t^Tc_sX_sds|\mathscr{F}_t]$$
>
> Where $X_t$ is the solution of the following SDE:
>
> $$dX_s=a_sX_sds + b_sX_sdB_s$$
>
> Where $s\in[t,T]$ and $X_t = 1$

Here comes the problem: how can we get the form of the solution of $Y_t$?

What I know is:
$$X_tY_t = E[X_T\xi-\int_t^T X_sc_sds|\mathscr{F}_t]$$
But how to transform it into the solution of $Y_t$?

Comment: Hum First as $X_t =1$ in Peng's result the point is trvial but then it appears that there is a typo either in the Peng's result as you report it or in your equation involving on the sign of the $\int_t^TX_s c_sds$ which are of opposite sign